# How to extract SE from function dose.p (package MASS) in R?

Tags: r

I'm using dose.p (from package MASS in R). I'm able to extract "Dose" but but not "SE".

```
#Sample
df <- data.frame(time = 1:10, value = c(0.9, 0.7, 0.5, 0.0, 0.3, 0.4, 0.0, 0.1, 0.1 ,0.0))

library(MASS)
my.glm<-glm(value ~ time, family=binomial(link="logit"), df)             
my.p50<-dose.p(my.glm, cf = c(1,2), p = 0.5)
my.p50

             Dose       SE
p = 0.5: 3.154826 1.634532
```

I can extract the "Dose" with;

```
my.p50[1]
```

but with;

```
my.p50[2]
```

I get;

```
<NA> 
  NA
```

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
unname(attributes(my.p50)$SE[, 1]) # unname is optional
[1] 1.634532
```

Take a look at the structure to know where to look for

```
str(my.p50)
#Class 'glm.dose'  atomic [1:1] 3.15
#  ..- attr(*, "SE")= num [1, 1] 1.63
#  .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
#  .. .. ..$ : chr "p = 0.5:"
#  .. .. ..$ : NULL
#  ..- attr(*, "p")= num 0.5
```